# SQL command, I would like to display some post from Wordpress with specific month and year in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wordpress

Here is my code to display posts from wordpress using mySQL.

SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content;

Now I would like to narrow down the display to a specific month and a specific year.
I just started SQL so please be easy with me.

Comment: Welcome to SQL, and welcome to SO, but newness isn't an excuse for laziness. We tend to like to see people make some effort to attempt/research problems themselves - and maybe familiarize themselves with the difference between MySQL, say, and SQL-Server

Comment: I spent more than 2 hours looking online but couldn't find a clear answer. Thank you for taking time to reply anyway.

Comment: There is no begineers guide to mysql, online or otherwise, that would not cover this. None.

Comment: Just save your time for someone else, don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get posts posted in May 2014 for example, you would use the below SQL:

> select * from  wp_posts where YEAR(post_date)='2014' and
>   MONTH(post_date)='05'

Or you could use this query:

> select * from  wp_posts where post_date >= '2014-05-01' and post_date < '2014-06-01'

Comment: Thank you very much. I realize there is so many way of doing it.

Comment: select * from wp_posts where YEAR(post_date)='2014' and MONTH(post_date)='05' and DAY(post_date)='25';                       Would this work for the day ?

Comment: You can just say where post_date = '2014-05-25'

Comment: If you really want to write the day, month and year separately, it would be written like this: select * from wp_posts where YEAR(post_date)='2014' and MONTH(post_date)='05' and DAYOFMONTH(post_date)='25';

Comment: @TonyMace if this answers your question, don't forget to accept the answer. If you have another followup question, let me know :)